# How to extract values from array along with other columns in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

> Hi,
>   I have a hive table with following columns 
>   partid string, store string and location array in table, values are save in this order

```
part123, store123, location 
[{"position":1,"price":124.0,"card_pos":"External","clicked":0},
 {"position":2,"price":94.78,"card_pos":"Cbox","clicked":0},
 {"position":3,"price":94.77,"card_pos":"External","clicked":0}] 
>
```

I can see values of arry in one line which is fine, I would also like to
see values from partid, store, location values in this way.
>

```
+---------+-----+----------+--------+-----------+----------+  
partid |store   | position | price  | card_pos  | clicked  |  
+---------+-----+----------+--------+-----------+----------+  
part123|store123| 1        | 124.0    | External | 0       |     
part123|store123| 2        | 94.78    | Cbox     | 0       |    
part123|store123| 3        | 94.77    | External | 0       |  
+---------+-----+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

>
So far I can only see array values by using inline function in this way.

```
select inline(location) as (position, price, card_pos, clicked) from table;  

>+---------+--------+-----------+----------+  
| position | price  | card_pos  | clicked  |  
+----------+--------+-----------+----------+  
| 1        | 124.0    | External | 0       |   
| 2        | 94.78    | Cbox     | 0       |  
| 3        | 94.77    | External | 0       |   
+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

>

Comment: just `select` those columns.

Comment: Yes, I did that too I am getting following error

Comment: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 1:39 AS clause has an invalid number of aliases. Error encountered near token 'price' (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lateral view` in conjunction with `inline` and select the other columns.

```
select partid,store,t.position,t.price,t.card_pos,t.clicked
from table
lateral view inline(location) t as position, price, card_pos, clicked
```

Edit: Per OP's request to handle cases when the `array` column is `null`, use `lateral view outer` option.

```
select partid,store,t.position,t.price,t.card_pos,t.clicked
from table
lateral view outer inline(location) t as position, price, card_pos, clicked
```

Comment: Thanks for your support it work for me, very much appreciate.

Comment: I have another question related to this topic, incase one record has only partid, store values are populated, and location array is NULL, how should I handle this, when I want to create one row in target table with partid, store populated with its values and position, price, card_pos, and clicked populate as NULL values, I do not want to loss that row, is lateral view inline take care of it? how should I handle it ....

Comment: Thanks again, one more question when I am selecting columns I am getting following error ... Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: **For input string: "PASSIVE" **(state=,code=0). Not sure why is it this exception?

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I tried the above method, I got an error that says 'The sub element must be struct, but was map<string,string>'